# Different colored lines in a DataGridView (DGV)

Tags: c#, datagridview, row, match

I have a Data Grid View and am wondering if it is possible to highlight only certain rows that contain a specific column value.

So I would like all of the rows to be defaulted to black with white text except for any row that has a specified column that equals **`FUJI/UNIVERSAL`**. For this row, I would like it to be yellow with black text.

So my question is.. is this possible? and if so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best place is the [RowPrePaint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.rowprepaint.aspx) event of the DataGridView.

Here is how you can achieve this.

```
void dataGridView1_RowPrePaint(object sender,
        DataGridViewRowPrePaintEventArgs e)
{
    if (dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value == "YourConditionalValue")
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Handle the OnPaint event for the `DataGridView` control.

Parse through the rows, and set the color on the rows that have the information you are looking for.

Some example code:

```
int specificColumnIndex = 5;
const string FUJIUNIV = "FUJI/UNIVERSAL";
const Color cFUJIBACK = Color.Yellow;
const Color cFUJITEXT = Color.Black;

public Form1() {
  InitializeComponent();
  dataGridView1.Paint += new PaintEventHandler(DataGridView_Paint);
}

private void DataGridView_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
  foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows) {
    if (row.Cells[specificColumnIndex].Value.ToString() == FUJIUNIV) {
      foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells) {
        cell.Style.BackColor = cFUJIBACK;
        cell.Style.ForeColor = cFUJITEXT;
        cell.Style.SelectionBackColor = Color.Gold;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

For example by handling the `OnCellFormatting` event.

Here's an actual piece of code from an old WinForms hobby project of mine, which does exactly that. It also teaches me again how important commenting is (no chance I would still remember it by now).

I' m sure you can adapt it to your purpose.

```
    private void sheetCalendar_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (CurrentRota == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        /* A word of explanation is needed. We retrieve the DataGridView from sender
         * and we access the cell in question directly. 
         * MSDN advices against it -
         * "to avoid performance penalties When handling this event,
         * access the cell through the parameters of the event handler
         * rather than accessing the cell directly."
         * 
         * The problem is that we don't want to set the same colour to the same cell
         * over and over again.
         * And e.CellStyle always "forgets" what colour the call had had! */
        var dgrid = sender as DataGridView;
        var _col = e.ColumnIndex; 
        var _row = e.RowIndex; 
        var _highlight = (((Rota) sheetCalendar.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem).Monday ==
                          CurrentRota.Monday);
        var color = _highlight ?
                                   Settings.Default.DGRIDCalendar_CurrentlyEditedBackColor :
                                                                                               SystemColors.Window;
        if (dgrid[_col, _row].Style.BackColor != color)
            dgrid[_col, _row].Style.BackColor = color;

    }
```